# Solve polynomial equation using Linked List

Tags: java, linked-list, postfix-notation, infix-notation

I am trying to write a Java program that takes an arithmetic expression, converts it from Infix to Postfix and evaluates the answer. However, I need to represent the expressions as Polynomials with the help of Linked Lists and perform Postfix evaluation on them. I have completed the Infix to Postfix conversion and know how to evaluate Postfix. But I am struggling to represent the polynomial expression using Linked List.

For example, if the Postfix expression is:   **40 50 -**

I need to store **40** as **4*10^1 + 0*10^1** in a Linked List. It can be done by having 2 nodes, Coefficient and Exponent, in the Linked List. Same thing for 50.

The problem is, I don't know how many linked lists I'll need for any given expression. If the postfix expression is   **40 50 60 - +**    then I need to store all 3 numbers in separate lists and  store them in a stack till I find an operator. Can anyone please give me any suggestions on how to proceed?

Comment: Are you sure you're meant to split an individual number into nodes in a linked-list (not just the whole expression)? That's very counter-intuitive and inefficient.

Comment: What about a [binary expression tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_expression_tree)?

Comment: When you write polynomial, do you really mean [polynomial](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial) or do you mean something else?

Comment: Sorry for the unclear question. I will give an example.

Input: (74625345320*675453284+45673)*(5555533333-4535423+4587678)

Output: 280034483624696616501207518164

Comment: It is basically an arithmetic precision package but I didn't mention it since I needed help only in this part. Sorry.

Comment: I am supposed to change the Base of the numbers from 10 to something big in order to perform arithmetic operations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to store the exponent in the linked list: the exponent can be given by the digit's position. For example 365 can be stored as the list `5->6->3`, though storing a single digit per list node is not so efficient.

You will need as many linked lists as there are input numbers, and you won't know how many there will be before reading the expression will you?

Comment: Thanks but how do I create those many linked lists? A loop? I have no idea how to proceed.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the problem. You can create a linked list every time you find a number while you are reading the input.

Comment: The input could have several expressions. All expressions could have different number of numbers. How do I create a new linked list every time I find a number? Should't each Linked List have a different name? Sorry I am a novice.

Comment: By name do you mean a variable? No, you don't need a new variable for every piece of data that a program processes. In this case, aren't you supposed to push the numbers onto a stack so that you can pull them out later for addition and subtraction?

Comment: Yes. I am supposed to push the operands onto the stack till I find an operator and then operate on the top two items in the stack and continue till there's only one item left in the stack which is the answer. If each number is represented as a linked list, I need to somehow store each linked list or its reference in the stack.

Comment: so that would be something like `"list = createlistfromdigits; stack.push(list)"`, right ?

Comment: So suppose I have 3 numbers 40, 50 and 60 in 3 separate linked lists L1, L2 and L3. What happens when I do stack.push(L1)? What is it that's exactly getting stored?

Comment: a reference to linked list L1

Comment: Thank you. One final question, whenever I find a number I need to create a linked list. If I find 40 I create a linked list "L1". So when I find the next number say 50, I need a Linked List "L2" right? So I need to name my linked lists in increments for each number I find. Is that correct?

Comment: By name do you mean a variable? No, you don't need a new variable for every piece of data that a program processes.